# Gwibber facebook login (was virus facebook login)

Tags: browser, facebook, default-browser

every minute a google-chrome pages is open with this url

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=.....
```

Where the token is my authentication token..

This is my ps aux result after killing chrome  (otherwise i would have tons of chrome opened..)

http://pastebin.com/G6yKjWJ5

I have ubuntu 12.10.

Any Idea?

EDIT: if I change firefox as default browser the page is opened with firefox

Comment: Not a virus... it is a redirect. Some might call it a feature others call it malware ;-) Does it persist when rebooted? If no: fine. Does it also happen with FF? If no: check settings in chrome and search your home directory for this URL (probably something like `cd ~ && grep facebook -R *`).

Comment: It *could* actually be malware. In this case it'd be considered one of those Facebook worms. They exist and have been seen in the past. If that were the case it would be some kind of cross-sitce scripting (XSS), at least likely.

Comment: @0xC0000022L and what's the solution? =)

Comment: The sure shot solution would be to close the browser, kill its cache and then check. In many cases that will be enough. If such worm "posts" on your Facebook wall (I'm not on Facebook, I only know the technical side because I work for an AV vendor) you may have to clean your profile, too. On the upside, *if* this is a Facebook worm, you can expect that Facebook takes automated steps to clean it up eventually. The issue remains that your profile could be compromised (i.e. change the password!) if this truly were the case.

Comment: I've found that is this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1058672

Comment: And this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1180297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is next to impossbile to determine if you have a virus from that information. However some key points:

1, You are using a Linux based system which isn't usually a target for virus writters. It's small market share doesn't warrent the effort.

2, I would check if chrome has any applications installed in it that you do not know about.

3, I would start disabling applications like Gwibber to determine which is trying let you know about facebook. Chances are some bug in a social application is causing this. I don't know if Unity has a lens for this or not.

4, Try switching default browsers to see if its chrome that has the problem or a system level problem.

Comment: 1) Has nothing to do with anything, there have been and will be Linux viruses in the wild, there may be currently (I don't keep up with malware news)

2) Has nothing to do with anything, if you click a dodgy link through a tor tunnel, you still execute the same code on your machine.

Comment: JS-based Facebook worms would work on script-enabled browsers regardless of the OS.

Comment: @JonStory I didn't imply that Linux doesn't have viruses. Just that its less likely. Rather than start from the premise of a virus, perhaps starting from the point that this is a bug in an application is a good idea.

Comment: @JonStory `and will be Linux viruses in the wild, there may be currently ` proof? I -do- keep up with that and NO virus has left the trial/testing stages (yet). "viruses" that need the user to install something are not viable ;) Besides that: we are educated to not click suspicious links or install random software from the web ... Oh wait ;-)

Comment: 4) Switched to firefox and page is displayed in firefox.

Comment: @Rinzwind: there *is* Linux malware out there. Call it "virus" or not. Most people not working in the AV industry use the terms synonymous anyway.

Comment: @0xC0000022L no we (;)) do not. Virus is malware. Malware is not perse a virus. To be classified as a virus or worm, malware must have the ability to **propagate**.

Comment: @Rinzwind: alright, you use plural to refer to yourself, fine. Fact is, most people I meet, do. And I work in the AV industry and know the fine nuances there. As for the "educated" part it sounds slightly arrogant, given that many a malware thrives on the basis of social engineering and "basic male instincts" ... I hope you get my drift. I have yet to see an end user, regardless of OS, to start up their disassembler and *look* into the binary they're about to install. Besides, malware only installed in your profile still can steal data. If that's its purpose why strive for root?

Comment: @FabioF. Since the problem is between browsers I would start by disabling applications until the pop-up stops: Messengers, Social Media, anything using OAuth to login, perhaps an indexer. Also double check your Cron tasks and Start up applications.

Comment: Killing gwibber has solved (at the moment) now i restart and try to  find out if it's really its fault.

Comment: @FabioF. There was a Gwibber update on my laptop this morning. Chances are good that its an authentication bug from that.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is trying to login to your fb account, disable Facebook in your Online accounts, that should do the trick